# how to save files in a folder in asp.net- error in path name

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("blablabla//"  + FileUpload1.FileName));
    }
```

This is the code behind my button for uploading a file to a folder in my web application in ASP.NET

But im getting an error that says `DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled by user code`.

How can i solve this error? The problem is the path name that leads to my folder called "blablabla",
I want to save files in this folder using a FileUpload control.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here are some samples that may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e7ykf56.aspx

Comment: Make sure you have the correct filepath. If you're unsure about it, assign the path to a local var in a line above that, set a break point there, make sure the path is what you expect it to be and that it does in fact exist on the server. Your path has no starting point (`./` would be the CWD) so I assume that is the source of your problems. If you want a relative path is probably needs to begin with `./`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should specify the destination path starting from the root folder of your site.
Also there is no need to dupe the forward slash

```
 FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/blablabla/"  + FileUpload1.FileName));
```

Comment: Also, make sure IIS has permissions to access the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Img_name = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string folder_path = Server.MapPath("~\\userimages\\");
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(folder_path + Img_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

string Path = Server.MapPath("/" + filename);

FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path);
```